# RANDOM DATES IN PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a question of how can I randomly insert dates with dmbs.random_value(minval,maxval) in pl/sql.

Comment: Could you set your title more explicit and explain us what you already tried & read about it ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might help; it is set to insert 10 (line #4) randomly (line #2) created date values in range between 01.01.2020 (`trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy')` and 100 days after that (max value in `dbms_random`).

```
SQL> create table test (datum date);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test (datum)
  2  select trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy') + round(dbms_random.value(1, 100)) + level
  3  from dual
  4  connect by level <= 10;

10 rows created.

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> select * from test;

DATUM
----------
02.04.2020
11.01.2020
16.01.2020
14.04.2020
07.04.2020
14.03.2020
29.01.2020
10.02.2020
26.03.2020
07.02.2020

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `NUMTODSINTERVAL` function to add a number of time units (days/hours/minutes/seconds, as appropriate) to an epoch time. For example, if you want to have a time between now and `1970-01-01` then you could calculate the total number of seconds between now and that epoch using:

```sql
( SYSDATE - DATE '1970-01-01' ) * 24 * 60 * 60
```

Then you can use that as an argument for `DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE`:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name ( value )
VALUES (
  DATE '1970-01-01'
  + NUMTODSINTERVAL(
      DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(
        0,
        ( SYSDATE - DATE '1970-01-01' ) * 24 * 60 * 60
      ),
      'SECOND'
    )
);
```

If you want to insert multiple values then you can repeat the insert or use a `SELECT` with a `CONNECT BY` clause:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name ( value )
SELECT DATE '1970-01-01'
       + NUMTODSINTERVAL(
           DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(
             0,
             ( SYSDATE - DATE '1970-01-01' ) * 24 * 60 * 60
           ),
           'SECOND'
         )
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 9;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ce801b9ae15709841effd54c139a80e8)*